# Problemas com versionamemto de codigo em reposotorio git no tfs

Tags: git, team-foundation-server

Criei um projeto testar o repositório git no tfs online
Criei o repositório e fiz o commit do codigo na branch master
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Mas ao olhar no repositório tfs, a branch esta vazia.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Bá, cara. Sacanagem postar essas fotos, né?

Comment: Faltou fazer o push do conteúdo local para o remoto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Falta fazer *push*.

No Git, os *commits* são feitos localmente. Para enviar suas alterações para o repositório remoto é preciso fazer um *push* das alterações.

Vá no painel lateral direito, no combo box (parte superior) selecione *Sync* e clique em *Push Changes*.

[image: Imagem do passo a passo]

Comment: +1 por ter sido mais rápido que eu (e por postar uma solução mais user friendly do que comandos de terminal).